# How to find a variable in js with a predetermined value?

Tags: javascript

I was [trying to modify an XHR `Get` request to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397654/how-to-debug-any-external-webview-from-an-app), but I have halfway given up on that task<sup>1</sup> to focus on modifying the source itself.

There are two JavaScript files that control the client side of the application. Say `a.js` and `b.js`. `b.js` is written by the 3rd-party-developer himself, `a.js` is a file that has been generated by an online service, meaning it is *heavily* minified.

The relation between `a.js` and `b.js` works in the following way:

- `a.js` has the values and parameters in some variable (say, `item=1` ) and uses `XTMLHttpRequest Object` to send it to `b.js`
- `b.js` just plays with the object - sends it to desired server/script etc...
- In short:

  - --> variables-->`a.js` -->send XHR Object --> `b.js` --> talks with server
  - I am thinking I cannot modify anything once it reaches `b.js` , so I have to modify things/values before an XHR Object is created (in `a.js`)

#### I will know:

- What values there will be, within the XHR Object
- What values there will be, in the XHR `Get` Request URI

  - The application basically works by changing the XHR Request URI
    from `xyz.com/index.html?item=1` to `xyz.com/index.html?item=2`

#### Problem?

When I use POSTMAN to send a request to `xyz.com/index.html?item=2` to the script, it acknowledges it with a response but does not update to the server. Something is blocking it. Therefore, I wish to change `item=2` before the XHR Object gets created in `a.js`

How can I monitor all the variables in the gigantic 15000+(*probably more*) lines of code in `a.js` for something to change from `0` to `5` or so?

---

<sup>1</sup> It yielded no feasible results

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was changing *blockquote* to ***bolditalic*** but okay..

Comment: So you're trying to change it from requesting `xyz.com/index.html?item=1` to make it request `xyz.com/index.html?item=2` instead? But when you do that `xyz.com/index.html?item=2` request via Postman it doesn't work? Why would you expect it to work when done by the script?

Comment: _“Something is blocking it. ”_ - then your efforts should concentrate on finding out what that “something” is, rather than trying to find workarounds that modify how 3rd-party scripts behave … no?

Comment: This is the likely *something* that debugging on default android browser showed me (I was not able to see this in **Chrome**, maybe I should rest on this now)

`Promise {<rejected>: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The origin of 'https://example.com/ind…}`

`__proto__:Promise`

`[[PromiseStatus]]:"rejected"`

`[[PromiseValue]]:TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The origin of 'https://example.com/index.html' should be same as 'https://www.example.org' at https://assets.example.net/index.js:1:99 at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: @04FS I wish it were that simple. The app and the script on the server is made by an independent 3rd-party-developer who I am not allowed to get in touch with(*and has a bit of a language barrier tbh between us*). I am not even allowed to touch the app's manifest(*which would have also worked*). I am on limited maneuverability here, but it'll be great if I can solve this interesting problem.